# How to USE BUSD for making metmask transaction

Tags: javascript, ethereum, smartcontracts, metamask, binance-smart-chain

I'm working on a dapp that sends BNB from wallet to wallet, as of now BNB transfer is achieved by the METAMASK send function, but now I want to send BUSD from wallet to wallet.
I'm not sure how I get the BUSD asset bind with the app so it asks the user to send BUSD instead of BNB.
Please help me to figure it our how I can make a BUSD transfer from metamask send function.

[image]

here I want to use BUSD instead BNB

[image]

Comment: What library are you using?!

Comment: I'm using metamask native api

Comment: For interacting with smart contract?! web3.js or ethers.js?!

Comment: web3 js for interacting

Comment: @SurrenderOz, Did you get the solution to transfer BUSD?

Answer (score 2):

I personally use ethers.js but I saw nobody answered your question so I give you some hints.

First, code is something like bellow:

```
let BUSD_ABI = ABI_OF_BUSD;
let BUSD_Contract_Address = BUSD_CONTRACT_ADDRESS;

let BUSD_Contract = new web3.eth.Contract(BUSD_ABI, BUSD_Contract_Address);

function sendBUSD(to, amount){
   BUSD_Contract.transfer(to, amount);
}
```

Second, You should use BUSD contract to interact with it and transfer BUSD to others. For interacting with contract check web3.js official site [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html).

Comment: When I'm making function call it gives me something error: 

""
Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": 3, "data": "0x000000", "message": "execution reverted: BEP20: transfer from the zero address" }""
-------------------------------
function code here:

""
  let x = 1 * (10**9)
    let num  = x.toString(16);
    await window.contract.methods.transfer("0xb928DcE388A8E20345E451caF33A7edC3f22A5E3", num).call();

""

Comment: This is weird! Is it BUSD contract you are interacting or other token?!